# jQuery/Sizzle checkContext memory leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

While debugging my app with 'Profiles' in DevTools I found "Detached DOM tree's" accumulating. These detached nodes have retaining tree consisting mostly of `checkContext` functions (coming from [sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) inside [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) - v1.10.1).

[image: Heap snapshot]

I'm not sure how to proceed with this. What does this result mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a bug, there's no reason that Sizzle needs to hang onto the context node, it's only doing it because it's not cleaning up after setting a temporary variable. I filed an [issue for it](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/issues/299), fixed it, ran all the Sizzle tests, and did a pull request.

If you want to patch your existing copy of jQuery or Sizzle:

1. Open your jQuery or Sizzle file
2. Search for the `matcherFromTokens` function
3. Find this code within it (near the top):

   ```
   matchers = [ function( elem, context, xml ) {
       return ( !leadingRelative && ( xml || context !== outermostContext ) ) || (
           (checkContext = context).nodeType ?
               matchContext( elem, context, xml ) :
               matchAnyContext( elem, context, xml ) );
   } ];
   ```
4. Change the `return` to `var rv =`, and add `checkContext = undefined;` and then `return rv;` at the end of the anonymous function, e.g.:

   ```
   matchers = [ function( elem, context, xml ) {
       var ret = ( !leadingRelative && ( xml || context !== outermostContext ) ) || (
           (checkContext = context).nodeType ?
               matchContext( elem, context, xml ) :
               matchAnyContext( elem, context, xml ) );
       // Release the context node (issue #299)
       checkContext = null;
       return ret;
   } ];
   ```

**Note**: That code assigns `null` to `checkContext` because apparently that's their style. If it were me, I'd've assigned `undefined` instead.

If there's any issue with the fix raised during the pull request / merge process, I'll update the answer.

It's better to keep letting Sizzle cache selectors, because jQuery uses the compiled selector stuff with event delegation, and you don't really want it to have to reparse and rebuild the matcher functions each time a relevant event occurs so it can figure out whether elements match it.

---

This isn't the only place jQuery holds onto elements in compiled selectors, unfortunately. Each place it does is probably a bug that could use fixing. I've only had the time to track down one other, which I've also reported and fixed (pending the pull request being landed):

If you search for *"Potentially complex pseudos"* you'll find this for the `:not` pseudo-selector:

```
pseudos: {
    // Potentially complex pseudos
    "not": markFunction(function( selector ) {
        // Trim the selector passed to compile
        // to avoid treating leading and trailing
        // spaces as combinators
        var input = [],
            results = [],
            matcher = compile( selector.replace( rtrim, "$1" ) );

        return matcher[ expando ] ?
            markFunction(function( seed, matches, context, xml ) {
                var elem,
                    unmatched = matcher( seed, null, xml, [] ),
                    i = seed.length;

                // Match elements unmatched by `matcher`
                while ( i-- ) {
                    if ( (elem = unmatched[i]) ) {
                        seed[i] = !(matches[i] = elem);
                    }
                }
            }) :
            function( elem, context, xml ) {
                input[0] = elem;
                matcher( input, null, xml, results );
                return !results.pop();
            };
    }),
```

The problem is in the function after the `:` in the conditional operator:

```
function( elem, context, xml ) {
    input[0] = elem;
    matcher( input, null, xml, results );
    return !results.pop();
};
```

Note that it never clears `input[0]`. Here's the fix:

```
function( elem, context, xml ) {
    input[0] = elem;
    matcher( input, null, xml, results );
    // Don't keep the element (issue #299)
    input[0] = null;
    return !results.pop();
};
```

That's all I have the time to track down at present.

Comment: So, you are saying that only matcher function was supposed to be cached? Not the whole result? That's why I haven't reported it, I thought Sizzle is caching matching DOM nodes on purpose.

Comment: @KonradDzwinel: Right. The function array is the part that needs to be reusable. As far as I can tell, `checkContext` is just a temporary variable, used so that `matchContext` and `matchAnyContext` have access to it when the anonymous function above calls them (I guess it can't pass it to them for some reason). There's no need to hold onto the context element after the matching is done (and every need *not* to). I was really surprised the fix was so easy, though, I thought we'd have to wait and clear it much later. But all the tests pass, so we'll see if it survives review...

Comment: This is huge for SPA apps using pure jQuery (jQlite doesn't use Sizzle)! Great work and thank you!

Comment: @KonradDzwinel: :-) Nice to have an opportunity to give back to jQuery/Sizzle. If the simple fix above doesn't pass muster, I'll keep at it, I know the Sizzle team will be supportive of not holding onto elements when we shouldn't.

Answer (score 6):

Sizzle stores compiled selectors in selector cache, which by default stores up to 50 entries. You may experiment by setting `$.expr.cacheLength = 1` before doing any selections and see if they go away.

Here's the docs https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation#-internal-api. Seems internal so don't depend on it or anything in actual production code.

Comment: Thanks! Changing cache length to 1 reduced number of detached nodes greatly. This feature may be useful for standard websites but it doesn't make sense for long running apps.

Comment: @KonradDzwinel I think it's exactly the opposite - a long running app will use same selectors over and over again which greatly benefits from the caching whereas a normal website typically just runs its selectors once. It is not a memory leak.

Comment: I agree that this is not a leak - it's controlled. However, in case of our app it's a problem - users often switch 'modules' and each module consists of lots of DOM nodes. We want to get rid of a previous 'module' as soon as the next one is loaded. Besides, we don't call same selectors multiple times - that would be embarrassing :)

Comment: @KonradDzwinel I don't mean multiple times written in code. I mean that in single page app, the jQuery selector cache persists between page changes and thus is actually likely to be hit. Whereas with full page load on every page will clear the cache and all selectors are always fully computed.

Comment: Each time module is opened it's rendered based on a template and injected into the DOM. Then, we fire up some selectors (mostly ID based) to catch the nodes we need to manipulate/listen and cache these ourselves in the variables. Whenever user changes the module we want to remove the previous one completely. With sizzle cache a lot of detached nodes stay in the memory. Therefore, I think that in case of our app - sizzle cache hurts more than it helps. Don't you agree?

Comment: hi @KonradDzwinel, i think i have similar flow structure as yours because i used backbonejs with requirejs. How this solution goes up to now? do you mind to share here

Comment: 50 is actually a really low number. IMO, it doesn't hurt for prod, but it's important to remove it when testing for memory leaks.

Comment: We got caught with this too.  Maddening feature that can definitely hurt an SPA badly.