# Backbone ListView creating zombies

Tags: listview, backbone.js, view, zombie-process

I am trying to build a simple crud application with a view of an item and the a listView containing that item view, built from a collection.  I want to have a detailView for a specific item, but when switching to this detailView, I do not know how to dispose of the listView properly.  I have seen solutions for removing zombies on a single view, but not for a view composed of a collection.  Is there any straight forward way to clean up a List view composed of views?

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults : {
    id : '',
    name : ''
}

});
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model : Model
})
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName : "div",
id : "home-view",
initialize : function() {
    $("body").html(this.el);
    this.render();
},
render : function() {
    this.$el.html("<h1>This is the home page</h1><a href='#users'>Go to users</a>");
}
});

var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName : "li",
initialize : function(e) {

    _.bindAll(this, "alertName");
    this.render();
},
events : {
    "click" : "alertName"
},
render : function() {
    this.$el.html("Hi, my name is " + this.model.get('name'));
},
alertName : function() {
    alert(this.model.get('name'));
}
});
var UsersView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName : "ul",
id : "users-list",
subViews : [],
initialize : function(e) {
    $("body").html(this.el);
    this.collection = new Collection([{
        id : '4',
        name : 'candy'
    }, {
        id : '2',
        name : 'soap'
    }, {
        id : '3',
        name : 'pepper'
    }]);
    console.log(this.collection)

    this.render();
},
render : function() {
    var self = this;
    this.collection.forEach(function(model) {

        var cView = new UserView({
            model : model
        })
        self.subViews.push(cView);
        self.$el.append(cView.el);
    })

    this.$el.after("<a href='#home'>Go to home</a>");
},
close : function() {

    while (this.subViews.length) {
        this.subViews.pop().remove();

    }

    this.remove();
}
});
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes : {
    "" : "home",
    "home" : "home",
    "users" : "users"
},
initialize : function(options) {
    console.log('router')

 },

  home : function(e) {
     console.log('home')
     this.loadView(new HomeView());

 },
users : function(e) {
    console.log('users');
      this.loadView(new UsersView());

},
loadView : function(view) {
    this.view && (this.view.close ? this.view.close() : this.view.remove());
    this.view = view;
}
});
$(document).ready(function() {

var router = new Router();
Backbone.history.start({

});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past this is what I've done:

Basically what you'll want to do is keep track of them when creating these new `ItemView`s. On your `ItemsView` create a hash of `children` keyed on `model.cid` or something (for quick lookup) or just an array of views.

Place a `remove` function on your `ItemsView` that when called will call up to the super Backbone.View#remove and loop through the `children` and call remove on each of them.

You can also put a `removeItemView` method on your `Itemsview` that takes a model and looks it up in your `children` and then calls `remove` on it.

Comment: Why use a `close` when we already have a [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) that calls `stopListening` and `this.$el.remove()`?

Comment: @muistooshort apologies.  Edited my answer, I'm so used to Marionette that has a `close` that I didn't remember that `Backbone.View` has a `remove` method.  Good catch!

Comment: how do you 'call up to the super backbone' and how do I reference the particular child view?

Comment: Basically in your `addOne` method you would do something like `this.children.push(appView);` then in your `remove` on `ItemsView` you would loop over each element in `this.children` and call `remove` on it.  As far as "calling super", you'll want to do something like this: `Backbone.View.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments)`

Comment: i'm able to create the array and remove them via a loop like you mention, but in Chrome's heap snapshot, I am still seeing all of the list view items as detached events.

Comment: Is the array that holds the children also getting dereferenced/the views being removed from that array?

Comment: Nothing to apologize for, AFAIK Derick start Marionette before Backbone had `View#remove`.

Comment: like this?:  for(var i=0; i<this.children.length; i++){
    
   this.children[i].remove();
   this.children.splice(i,1);
   
  }

Comment: You should go backwards through the array that way your iteration isn't messed up (since you are removing items from the array) or do a while loop that runs while `this.children.length`

Comment: good point.  there is clearly something more fundamental wrong with my application as it is still not working. i'll try to set up a better example and see if I can be clearer on my issue.

Comment: Thinking about it some more you should just be able to do `while(this.children.length)` and just do `this.children.pop()` on it since the order that you close really doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @user2961953 this line also seems like a problem.. `this.$el.append(ItemView.render().el);`.  I believe that should be `appView.render().el` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I found a helpful blog post (http://mikeygee.com/blog/backbone.html) and used your suggestions to handle the listViews cleanup.

Comment: I do have one more question.  What if I was to remove a single item from the lists view?  It would still be in the subViews array and it could not be accessed from the list view.

Comment: Make a method called `removeItemView` that takes a model, loops through your `subViews` array and finds the view that has a `view.model == model`.  Call `.remove` on it and splice it out of your `subViews` array.

Comment: That makes sense from the listView, but the remove if taking place at the single view level, which wouldn't have access to the listViews methods or variables

Comment: I see.  In your `itemView` trigger an event when `ItemView#remove` is called that does this: (this.trigger('removed')) and when you're adding the item view in the `ItemsView` then listen to the itemView for that custom event and call `removeItemView` that I told you about above.

Comment: Thanks again. You have helped me a great deal.  One note:  Some of the memory leaks being caused were from jquery sizzle cache. I followed the instructions here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279143/jquery-sizzle-checkcontext-memory-leak  and it fixed the remaining leaks I couldn't get rid of.